# How to make a copy of bits with dynamic_bitset<>

Tags: c++, boost

I have this function:

```
void SetCode(dynamic_bitset<> * c) {  
    this->_code = c;  
    this->_size = c->size();  
}
```

Where it says: `this->_code = c`, I want to make a copy of `c` and put it in `this->_code`.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `this->_code` is the same `dynamic_bitset<>` as `c`. You can just use the assignment operator (this requires `_code` to already be initialized, i.e. `new`ed):

```
*_code = *c;
```

You should probably remove the pointer from the type of `this->_code` and use a reference in the parameter instead:

```
class A {
public:
  void foo (boost::dynamic_bitset<T, U>& c)
  {
    _code = c;
  }

private:
  boost::dynamic_bitset<T, U> _code;
};
```

You didn't supply any of the template parameters for `dynamic_bitset` so I just chose two fake ones.

Comment: I have tried this way but then i'm getting program stopped working ... :)

Comment: @BenasRadzevicius, did you really initialize _code before you did that?